# I want to add a x button to close a material popper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have made a  material ui popper I have added a button (x) to close the popper.

I have added a button and a const handleClose that is supposed to close the popper when clicked, but this is not working (Nothing happens) each popper has its own class

This is my experiences const where my popper is created

```
const Experiences = memo(
  (props) => {
    const { className } = props;
    const classes = useStyles(props);

    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    const handleClick = (event) => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    // const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl({
      open: false
    });
  };

    const experience = (img, title, id, popoverCategory) => (
      <div
        className="experience"
        aria-describedby={id}
        id={id}
        onClick={handleClick}
        onKeyDown={handleClick}
        role="button"
        tabIndex="0"
      >
        <img
          data-sizes="auto"
          className="lazyload"
          data-src={img}
          alt={title}
        />
        <div className="experience-title">
          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="highlight highlight1"
            display="inline"
          >
            { title }
          </Typography>
        </div>

        <Popper
          id={id}
          open={anchorEl && anchorEl.id === id}
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          className={clsx(classes[id])}
          modifiers={{
            flip: {
              enabled: false,
            },
          }}
        >         
          <Button onClickAway={handleClose}>x</Button>
          <div className={clsx(classes.paper)}>
            {
              popoverCategory.map(url => (

                <img
                  key={id}
                  data-sizes="auto"
                  className="lazyload"
                  src={url}
                  alt={title}
                />
              ))
            }
          </div>
        </Popper>
      </div>

    );
```

Comment: where you set anchorEl ? share anchorEl setting code

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi I updated my question so you see the rest of the code

Comment: Please look at how to ask a question. This doesn't seem like a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We're all volunteering our time, if you can get this down to fewer lines of code we can answer you more easily. Additionally you might find the answer when trying to get it down to that minimal example and answer it yourself. If so, post your own answer and still edit your code. If you looked for the answer and couldn't find it, help out the next person (and get a badge for answering your own question).

Comment: Can you also please be more specific than "it isn't working". What, precisely, is not working for you.

Comment: @Rodger I edited my question I hope its more understandable. Sorry I am new to React, Material and havent used stack that much.

Comment: @DrewReese When I click on the button x inside the popper nothing happens.

Comment: @NaNodine Glad you got it worked out, but I meant more to explain *how* it isn't working, what you had tried to get it working, any evidence of what you've debugged, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method :

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Popper from '@material-ui/core/Popper';
import gastronomia from 'assets/experiences/gastronomia.jpg';
import productos from 'assets/experiences/productos.jpg';
import giftcard from 'assets/experiences/giftcard.jpg';
import diversion from 'assets/experiences/diversion.jpg';
import deporte from 'assets/experiences/deporte.jpg';
import belleza from 'assets/experiences/belleza.jpg';
import gastronomiaExperiences from 'data/gastronomia';
import productosExperiences from 'data/productos';
import giftcardExperiences from 'data/giftcard';
import diversionExperiences from 'data/diversion';
import deporteExperiences from 'data/deporte';
import bellezaExperiences from 'data/belleza';


// Proptypes definitions to the component.
const propTypes = {
  /** Custom root className. */
  className: PropTypes.string,

};

// Default props definitions.
const defaultProps = {
  className: null,
};

// Component's styles
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'block',
    margin: '0 auto',
    maxWidth: '50%',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
      maxWidth: '70%',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
      maxWidth: '100%',
    },
    '& .experiences-column': {
      display: 'inline-block',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      textAlign: 'center',
      '&.col1': {
        width: '36.31%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '&.col2': {
        width: '63.69%',
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
          width: 'initial',
        },
      },
      '& .experience': {
        padding: 2,
        position: 'relative',
        '& img': {
          width: '100%',
          display: 'block',
        },
        '& .experience-title': {
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 30,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          textAlign: 'center',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  gastronomia: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,185,208,0.9)',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: '-220px',
    marginLeft: '25%',
    width: '50%',
    height: '220px',
  },
  giftcard: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(221,165,174,0.9)',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: '-320px',
    marginLeft: '25%',
    width: '50%',
    height: '320px',
  },
  deporte: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(189,143,205,0.9)',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: '-320px',
    marginLeft: '25%',
    width: '50%',
    height: '320px',
  },
  productos: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(221,165,174,0.9)',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: '-220px',
    marginRight: '18%',
    width: '50%',
    height: '220px',
  },
  diversion: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,176,10,0.9)',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: '-320px',
    marginRight: '18%',
    width: '50%',
    height: '320px',
  },
  belleza: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(229,166,187,0.9)',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: '-320px',
    marginRight: '18%',
    width: '50%',
    height: '320px',
  },
  paper: {
    '& img': {
      width: '180px',
      padding: '0 10px 0 10px',
    },
  },

}), { name: 'ExperiencesStyle' });


/**
 * Component used to render a grid of experiences.
 *
 * @param {object} props - The component's props.
 * @returns {object} React element.
 */
const Experiences = memo(
  (props) => {
    const { className } = props;
    const classes = useStyles(props);

    const [poperOpen, setPoperOpen] = React.useState([]); // array of popers states
    const [justChange, setJustChange] = React.useState(false); // array of popers states

    // one handle click for open/close    
    const handleClick = (e, _id, _open) => {
       let idx = poperOpen.findIndex(x => x.id === _id);

       // for show just one comment this lines : 
       //let a = poperOpen;
       //if(idx > -1 ){
          a.splice(idx, 1);
       //}
       let a = [];
       a.push({id: _id, open: _open, anchorEl: e.currentTarget}); 

       setPoperOpen(a);
       setJustChange(!justChange);
    };

    const experience = (img, title, id, popoverCategory, dontRemoveMe) => (
     <div>
      <div
        className="experience"
        aria-describedby={id}
        id={id}
        onClick={(e)=>handleClick(e, id, true)} 
        onKeyDown={(e)=>handleClick(e, id, true)}
        role="button"
        tabIndex="0"
      >
        <img
          data-sizes="auto"
          className="lazyload"
          data-src={img}
          alt={title}
        />
        <div className="experience-title">
          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            variant="subtitle2"
            className="highlight highlight1"
            display="inline"
          >
            { title }
          </Typography>
        </div>
        </div>

        <Popper
          id={id}
          open={poperOpen.findIndex(x => x.id === id) > -1 && poperOpen.find(x => x.id === id).open }
          anchorEl={poperOpen.findIndex(x => x.id === id) > -1 ? poperOpen.find(x => x.id === id).anchorEl : undefined} 
          className={clsx(classes[id])}
          modifiers={{
            flip: {
              enabled: false,
            },
          }}
        >         
          <Button onClick={(e)=>handleClick(e, id, false)}>x</Button>
          <div className={clsx(classes.paper)}>
            {
              popoverCategory.map(url => (

                <img
                  key={id}
                  data-sizes="auto"
                  className="lazyload"
                  src={url}
                  alt={title}
                />
              ))
            }
          </div>
        </Popper>
      </div>

    );

    return (

      <div className={clsx(classes.root, className)}>
        <div className="experiences-column col1">
          {experience(gastronomia, 'GASTRONOMÍA', 'gastronomia', gastronomiaExperiences, justChange)}
          {experience(giftcard, 'GIFT CARD', 'giftcard', giftcardExperiences, justChange)}
          {experience(deporte, 'DEPORTE', 'deporte', deporteExperiences, justChange)}
        </div>
        <div className="experiences-column col2">
          {experience(productos, 'PRODUCTOS', 'productos', productosExperiences, justChange)}
          {experience(diversion, 'DIVERSIÓN', 'diversion', diversionExperience, justChanges)}
          {experience(belleza, 'BELLEZA', 'belleza', bellezaExperiences, justChange)}
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  },
);

// Component proptypes.
Experiences.propTypes = propTypes;

// Component default props.
Experiences.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Experiences;
```

Simple demo :[HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-leaf-futi9)

Comment: I used your code and the popper did not open... I added const to handleClick function becouse I got the error  Line 151:5:   'handleClick' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Move handleClick out side of Experiences and inside of your component. this is just a sample code, see my demo on codesandbox

Comment: I get these errors when I move handleClick outside of Experiences   Line 34:1:    'handleClick' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 35:19:   'poperOpen' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 36:17:   'poperOpen' is not defined     no-undef
  Line 41:9:    'setPoperOpen' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 168:23:  'handleClick' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 169:25:  'handleClick' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 201:37:  'handleClick' is not defined   no-undef

Comment: make a simple project of your code on codesandbox to check

Comment: I uploaded my project to codesandbox... https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-fog-botmq

Comment: This keeps every popper I click on one and I want just one at a time How would I do that?